Start editing a gtk_editable_label with double click, not single click in gtk_column_view
I have gtk_editable_label as cell widget in a gtk_column_view. So far so good, but when I make a single click in the cell, it places a entry so I can change to contents. I would like to have this action BUT in a double click. Any ideas?
void fac_setup (GtkSignalListItemFactory *factory,GObject  *listitem)
{
    GtkWidget *label = gtk_editable_label_new (NULL);
    gtk_list_item_set_child (GTK_LIST_ITEM (listitem), label);
}

// ***

GtkListItemFactory *factory = gtk_signal_list_item_factory_new();
g_signal_connect (factory, "setup", G_CALLBACK(fac_setup), NULL);

Update 1 (05/31/2024):
void cb_gesture_pressed ( GtkGestureClick* self, gint n_press, gdouble x, gdouble y, gpointer user_data)
{
    if (n_press == 2)
        gtk_editable_set_editable (GTK_EDITABLE (user_data), TRUE);
}

void factory_setup (GtkListItemFactory *factory, GtkListItem *list_item, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *widget_item;
    int i = GPOINTER_TO_INT (user_data);
    GObject *item = gtk_list_item_get_item (list_item);
    
    if (i != ID_GRADE)
    {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/a/77180065/2030219
        widget_item = gtk_editable_label_new ("");
        gtk_editable_set_editable (GTK_EDITABLE (widget_item), FALSE);
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/78560182/2030219 &&
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/76614510/2030219
        GtkGesture *gesture = gtk_gesture_click_new ();
        g_signal_connect (gesture, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (cb_gesture_pressed), widget_item);
        gtk_widget_add_controller (widget_item, GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture));
    }
    else
    {
        widget_item = gtk_spin_button_new_with_range (0, 10, 1);
        gtk_spin_button_set_wrap (GTK_SPIN_BUTTON (widget_item), TRUE);
    }
    
    gtk_list_item_set_child (list_item, widget_item);
}

The above code works as expected, only double click doesn't bring the entry text, I need one more click so the entry appear to modify the editable.

My idea would be to write your own class derived from GtkWidget. Use GtkEditableLabel internally and implement the desired double-click.
To make the answer complete, here is an example of what a dedicated editable label might look like:
class-editabele-label.h
/* An editable label that responds to double-click. */

#pragma once
#include<gtk/gtk.h>

#define  EDITABLE_TYPE_LABEL (editable_label_get_type())
 
G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE (EditableLabel, editable_label,  EDITABLE, LABEL, GtkWidget)
 
GtkWidget *editable_label_new(char*);

void editable_label_insert_text(EditableLabel *self,char *text);


class-editable-label.c
#include"class-editable-label.h"

struct _EditableLabel
{
  GtkWidget parent_instance;
  GtkWidget *editable;
};
 
struct _EditableLabelClass
{
  GtkWidgetClass parent_class;
};
 
G_DEFINE_TYPE (EditableLabel, editable_label, GTK_TYPE_WIDGET)

// delete all and insert new text   
void editable_label_insert_text(EditableLabel *self,char *text)
{
 int position;
 gtk_editable_delete_text(GTK_EDITABLE(self->editable),0,-1);
 gtk_editable_insert_text(GTK_EDITABLE(self->editable),text,-1,&position);
}


void cb_gesture_pressed ( GtkGestureClick* self, gint n_press, gdouble x, gdouble y, gpointer user_data)
{
    if (n_press == 2)
        gtk_editable_set_editable (GTK_EDITABLE (EDITABLE_LABEL(user_data)->editable),TRUE);
       gtk_editable_label_start_editing(GTK_EDITABLE_LABEL(EDITABLE_LABEL(user_data)->editable));

    else
        gtk_editable_set_editable (GTK_EDITABLE (EDITABLE_LABEL(user_data)->editable),FALSE);
}

static gboolean on_key_pressed(GtkEventControllerKey *controller, 
                           guint keyval,
                           guint keycode,
                           GdkModifierType state,
                           gpointer user_data)
{
   // filter out Enter and TAB
   if(keycode == 36  || keycode == 23)
   {
    gtk_editable_label_stop_editing (GTK_EDITABLE_LABEL(EDITABLE_LABEL(user_data)->editable),TRUE);
    gtk_editable_set_editable (GTK_EDITABLE (EDITABLE_LABEL(user_data)->editable),FALSE);
   }    

    return GDK_EVENT_PROPAGATE;
}

static void 
editable_label_dispose (GObject *gobject)
{
    EditableLabel *self = EDITABLE_LABEL (gobject);
    g_clear_pointer(&self->editable, gtk_widget_unparent);  
    G_OBJECT_CLASS (editable_label_parent_class)->dispose (gobject);

}

static void
editable_label_init(EditableLabel *self)
{
    self->editable = gtk_editable_label_new("");
    GtkGesture *gesture = gtk_gesture_click_new ();
    g_signal_connect (gesture, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (cb_gesture_pressed), self);
    gtk_widget_add_controller (GTK_WIDGET(self), GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture));
    // filter out Enter and TAB
    GtkEventController*  keyevent = gtk_event_controller_key_new ();
    gtk_widget_add_controller(GTK_WIDGET(self->editable),keyevent);
    g_signal_connect_after(keyevent,"key-pressed",G_CALLBACK(on_key_pressed),self);

    gtk_editable_set_editable (GTK_EDITABLE(self->editable),FALSE);
    gtk_widget_set_parent(GTK_WIDGET(self->editable), GTK_WIDGET(self));
    // LayoutManager can be changed !!
    GtkLayoutManager *center_layout;
    center_layout = gtk_widget_get_layout_manager (GTK_WIDGET(self));
    gtk_center_layout_set_start_widget (GTK_CENTER_LAYOUT (center_layout),self->editable);
}

static void
editable_label_class_init (EditableLabelClass *class)
{
  G_OBJECT_CLASS(class)->dispose = editable_label_dispose;
  GtkWidgetClass *widget_class = GTK_WIDGET_CLASS (class);
  // LayoutManager
 gtk_widget_class_set_layout_manager_type(widget_class,GTK_TYPE_CENTER_LAYOUT); 
}
 
GtkWidget *
editable_label_new (char *text)
{
  EditableLabel *self;
 
  self = g_object_new (EDITABLE_TYPE_LABEL,NULL);
  if (text != NULL)
  {   
   int position;
   gtk_editable_insert_text(GTK_EDITABLE(self->editable),text,-1,&position);
  }
  return GTK_WIDGET (self);
 }

I have tested this class with the example of https://stackoverflow.com/a/77759424/22768315. It works when using "GtkNoSelection". It should be noted, however, that the edited information will not be written back to the ListModel. So you have a table that you cannot sort, for example.
A GtkGrid may have a more appropriate solution.
Greetings

Thanks, I'll try this idea as plan B.

Just set the "senstive" property of Gtk.EditableLabel to False, which will prevent it from receiving keyboad focus. So, create a function that changes "senstive" and "editing" to True and puts the keyboard focus on Gtk.EditableLabel and bind this function to double click.
You will probably also need a function that sets the "senstive" of Gtk.EditableLabel back to False connected to the "editing" signal of Gtk.EditableLabel.

When you say "back to False" I know how to handle that signal, but the first part: seems that button-events are not longer part of gtk4 to catch double click, what signal is?

You will have to add a Gtk.GestureClick to your Gtk.EditableLabel (or to your custom widget that contains the Gtk.EditableLabel) to capture the click action.

I manage to follow your suggestions as you can see update 1 in my code. Only need an extra click so entry widget appeat to edit.

Call gtk_editable.grab_focus function below the "gtk_editable_set_editable" in your cb_gesture_pressed.

In my example, I had to use the function "gtk-editable-label-start-editing".
